# Sequelize createdAt Unable to modify

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I can't seem to modify the result of createdAt and updatedAt.
The result is 2018-06-08T04:40:18.596Z

When I render it in html : Created Fri Jun 08 2018 12:40:18 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time)

I tried to trim them to no avail. How do I modify it e.g getting the day and year only?

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you?

```
function day_year (date, join) {

  let d = new Date(date)
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + d.getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000)

  let day = '' + d.getDate()
  let year = d.getFullYear()

  if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day

  return [day, year].join(join)

}

let updated_at = '2018-06-08T04:40:18.596Z'

console.log(day_year(updated_at, '-')) // 08-2018
console.log(day_year(updated_at, '/')) // 08/2018
```

Comment: Added timezone offset.

Answer (score 0):

The first and easier method would be to use the Date Object in Javascript

```
const date = new Date('2018-06-08T04:40:18.596Z')
const day = date.getDate() // will give you 8 (number between 1-31)
const month = date.getMonth() // will give you 5 (number between 0-11)
const year = date.getFullYear() // will give you 2018
```